# A simple vector, how can I reassign the address for a new array correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create a simple version of a vector. It seems to be working if I look only at what I am storing, but there is one thing that concerns me. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char* arr = new char[1];
    int size = 1; // current size of the array
    int num_chars = 0; // how many characters are stored so far
    char c;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << ">";
        cin >> c;
        if (c == '!') break;
        if (num_chars == size)
        {
            size *= 2;
            char* new_arr = new char[size];
            cout << "Old array address: " << &arr << endl;
            cout << "New array address: " << &new_arr << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++)  // copy arr to new_arr
                new_arr[i] = arr[i];
            delete[] arr;
            arr = new_arr;
        }
        arr[num_chars++] = c;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_chars; i++)
            cout << arr[i];
        cout << endl;
        cout << &arr << endl;
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

the program accepts characters one at a time, and they are stored in an array which grows dynamically, finishing when you enter an exclamation mark. I added some cout statements to check my input and where the arrays are being stored.

When I allocate new_arr it gets a new address, then I copy over the memebers of arr to the new arr, delete arr, and assign arr to point to new_arr. The part that concerns me is that when I check the memory locations of arr after it gets reassigned, it's the same as it was before, so it looks like I'm just writing past the end of the original array. How can I correctly reassign the pointer to the new array?

Here is some sample output:

```
>a
a
0x7fff5fbff760
>b
Old array address: 0x7fff5fbff760
New array address: 0x7fff5fbff748
ab
0x7fff5fbff760
>c
Old array address: 0x7fff5fbff760
New array address: 0x7fff5fbff748
abc
0x7fff5fbff760
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing out addresses of pointers themselves, not addresses of the arrays (i.e. the contents of the pointers).

The location in memory where you store the address of the array (i.e. the address of variable `arr`) stays the same. It's not supposed to change. Thus, `&arr` is always the same. But the *value* stored in that location does change (as it would be expected).

Change the code to

```
cout << "Old array address: " << static_cast<void*>(arr) << endl;
```

and see the difference.

(`static_cast<void*>(arr)` casts type of `arr` from `char*` to `void*`. The reason to do this is that `cout` treats `char*` as a pointer to null-terminated string, and prints the contents of the string instead of the pointer's value. However, if we change the type of the pointer to something that `cout` does not interpret (e.g. `void*`), then `cout` will just print the address.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Perhaps it's my compiler/IDE (Xcode 6) but when I tried without the & on that line it simply printed out the contents of the array instead of the address. I don't know how to resolve that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm being stupid, of course it will print the contents when given `char*`. Just cast it to another pointer type, e.g. `void*`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That works perfectly! I cast it to (int*) and it printed out the addresses correctly. Looks like my program actually is working as intended, I'm just not so good with pointers yet. Thanks for the help.